# vba: saveas in xlsm fileformat without changing the active workbook

Tags: excel, save-as, xlsm, vba

I have the following code which makes copies of the active workbook and gives each copy a different name. It works well, BUT I really need the original worksheet from which the code is run to stay active.

If I use the `SaveCopyAs` function instead, the copied files do not have the correct file format (.xlsm), and you cannot specify the file format as a parameter as in the `saveAs` function.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb178003%28v=office.12%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185%28v=office.15%29.aspx

```
    Sub makeCopies()
        Dim name As Range, team As Range
        Dim uName As String, fName As String, fFormat As String
        Dim location as string, nName as string

        location ="c:\test\"
        nName = "Test - Team "
        Set team = Names("Team").RefersToRange

        For Each name In team
            uName = nName & name.Value
            fName = location & uName
            fFormat = ThisWorkbook.FileFormat
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=fName, FileFormat:=fFormat
        Next name
   End sub
```

The best I can think of is to first make the copies with `saveCopyAs` and then access each file, save it in the correct file format with `saveAs` and then close it, but that means double work, and I would really hate to do that. Is there a smarter way?

Comment: Well, as it happens I actually do. This is exactly what the FileFormat parameter does, please refer to my second link in the post and  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works form me. `SaveCopyAs` saves the workbook in the exact same format.

```
Sub makeCopies()
    Dim name As Range, team As Range
    Dim uName As String, fName As String, tempname As String
    Dim location As String, nName As String

    location = "C:\Test\"
    nName = "Test - Team "
    Set team = ThisWorkbook.Names("Team").RefersToRange

    For Each name In team
        uName = nName & name.Value
        fName = location & uName & "." & _
            Split(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".") _
            (UBound(Split(ThisWorkbook.FullName, ".")))
        ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs fName
    Next name
End Sub
```

Is this what you're trying? Tried and tested.

Comment: Interesting if this works. I'll give it a shot and get back. I think you made a small error with the tempname var, though. You're not using it anywhere...

Comment: @Miqi180 A yeah, I tested it using another approach :) If this works which I think will then we don't have to resort to that :D

Comment: hrrmm, I guess my computer must have had the flu or something, because I swear the saveCopyAs function was the first thing I tried, including setting the file extension as a string (".xlms") and adding it to the end of the filename. This is completely equivalent to what you're doing, except your code is dynamic and will work for all file extensions. Anyway, it works as expected now. Thanks. Good call! :)