# VBScript to Open an Excel File and then do a Save As

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I am trying to write a vba script to automatically open an excel file increase the day by one in a certain cell and then wait 2 minutes for all other field to populate information from the current day. Once the other field are populated I want the script to close the file and save as the day it ran the script. I am going to add this script to windows task manager to run daily at 2 am. so far I have something like this.

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("c:\Users\dr\Desktop\test.xlsx")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True
objExcel.Workbooks.Add
objExcel.Cells(3, 2).Value = "=today()"

WScript.Sleep 120000

wb.SaveAs Format( Now(), “DD-MMM-YY”)
```

Comment: Where exactly are you running into problem?

Answer (score 3):

Your script needs to open the Workbook, then update the day, calculate ("populate the other cells"), save and close. My advice is to not use Sleep for this, but just force the Workbook to calculate and then close it. Like @iDevlop says: Changing the formula in B3 is unneccessary. The same goes for actually showing the Excel application.

The following opens the workbook, recalculates (so the B3 value will be today's date and the rest of the workbook will calculate accordingly), and saves:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("c:\Users\dr\Desktop\test.xlsx")
objExcel.Calculate
objWorkbook.SaveAs Format( Now(), “DD-MMM-YY”)
```

For info on `.calculate` see https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff195517.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Not very sure to fully understand your question, but I already see one or 2 fixes:

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("c:\Users\dr\Desktop\test.xlsx")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True
'objExcel.Workbooks.Add
objWorkbook.Sheets("sheetName").Cells(3, 2).Value = "=today()"

WScript.Sleep 120000

objWorkbook.SaveAs "F" & format(date(), "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsm", 52
```

Anyway, changing the formula in B3 to `"=Today()"` everyday is totally useless, since it was already that same formula the day before.

---

**Edit:** if you are running this from an Excel VBA procedure, you don't *need* to create a new instance of Excel:

```
dim sFolder as string
sFolder = "c:\Users\dr\Desktop\"
Set objWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(sFolder & "test.xlsx")
objWorkbook.Sheets("sheetName").recalc
objWorkbook.SaveAs sFolder & format(date(), "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"
objWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am getting an error 
Line 10
Char 56
Error Invalid Character
Code 800A0408
Source Microsoft VBScript copilation error.
Also for the Save as function how can add something like test.day.xlms

Comment: For the SaveAs, look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/25214233/78522.  
For the rest, look at my Edit

Comment: Can you tell me how I can add to the script after it does the sleep I want the script to select the entire worksheet do a copy and past as a special value of "values". I still can't get the saveas function working. I want the file to save as in the path "c:\Users\dr\Desktop\test-today.xlsx")

Comment: I got most of my code working. No matter what I do I can't get the objWorkbook.SaveAs Method working properly. I want to save the file in a specific location with the name+date or just the date as the name does not matter. It should be a xlsx file format. Please help.

Comment: @DannyR XLSX is format *without macro*, the sheet will save without macro. To get that, just drop the `, 52` at the end of the `SaveAs`line, and perhaps add a full path in front of the name. Do you have an error ? which one ?

Comment: So this is the script I have so far

`Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\dr\Desktop\Test\FWDCURVE_BUILDER_S23.xlsm")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True

WScript.Sleep 12000

objExcel.Application.Run "Update()"

objWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\dr\Desktop\test\" & format(date(), "yyyymmdd") & ".xlsx"

objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

objExcel.Application.Quit`

the error i am getting is 
line 10
char 1
error type mismatch: 'format'
code 800A000D

Comment: Why are you speaking about "script" ? Is this VBA or vbScript ?

Comment: I am trying to write a VBScript. I will break down exactly what I am trying to accomplish with the script.
1. Open up an excel file.
2. Once opened the cells will auto populate based on the date it is opened so I need it to stay open for 2 minutes.
3. Have the script run a VBA Macro to copy all the cells and then paste it back into the spread sheet as values.
4. Close and Save As with the date it was run.
I think I got most of the code working just can't get the last save as part to work. 
thank you for your help.

Comment: you should rather `edit`your question and your tags, because they are misleading

Comment: Sorry new to this site.

Comment: so with the vbscript *.vbs extension I am having trouble saving a file. I am trying to save the file back into the folder it is located like c:\files\test.xls but I want it renamed to test02072016.xls where 02072016 is the date the script is run. @iDevlop

Comment: If you still have trouble, I really suggest you write your script using Excel VBE, and when that works, you copy paste most of it to you vbs.

Comment: I tried to create the macro in excel VBE and got it working, however when I copy it to my VBS script it doesn't work. I need it to work in the VBS script not excel VBE.