# How can I run a .txt macro on many .xslx files without having to change the .xlsx file?

Tags: excel, vba

I'll give an example. So, lets say I have this very simple macro:

```
Sub updateOneCell(cellNumber As String, cellLetter As String, updatedValue As String)

    Range(cellLetter & cellNumber).value = updatedValue

End Sub
```

How do I run this macro which is saved as a .txt on multiple .xlsx without having to convert the .xlsx to .xlsm? Also without having to open up the .xlsx files.

Comment: What about using a .VBS file for this purpose?

Comment: @Tarik can you link me to an example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35132469/vbscript-to-open-an-excel-file-and-then-do-a-save-as

Comment: To get list of XLS files in folder: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4200028/vbscript-list-all-pdf-files-in-folder-and-subfolders

Answer (score 0):

Maybe storing the code in a separate **.xlsm** workbook will appropriate solution? You can run the code directly from the **.xlsm** workbook and change all the **.xlsx** files at once.

Changing data in a closed workbook is not possible (as far as I know)... maybe if changing the byte content of the file directly which, I guess, isn't a very nice solution. Instead, you can hide the workbooks that you want to edit with `ActiveWindow.Visible = False`.

Comment: Changing data in a closed workbook may be possible using a third-party library, but I don't know how much it improves (or decreases) the speed.  For suppressing rendering, ``Application.ScreenUpdating = False`` may be better because it stops all screen updates.